# How to extract text which lies after <strong> tag in element

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to extract text from a element which looks like this:

```
<div><strong>"Beginning_of_text"</strong>"Rest_of_text"</div>
```

When I try to extract `"Rest_of_text"` using Scrapy shell with

```
response.css("div::text").extraxt()
```

It gives me nothing. Do I have to use some special command to get to text that lies after a `<strong>` tag inside an element?

Comment: Try `response.xpath("//div/text()").extract()` or `response.xpath("//div/strong/following-sibling::text()").extract()`

Comment: "Beginning_of_text" : response.css("div strong::text").extract() maybe?

Comment: Try using `response.css("div::text").extract()` in place of `response.css("div::text").extraxt()` to get `"Rest_of_text"` as result. There is no such thing ***`.extraxt()`*** in scrapy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the text you provided, the command you've mentioned should've returned the following:

```
['"Rest_of_text"']
```

The problem may occur if there is whitespace before `strong` tag, e.g.:

```
<div>   <strong>"Beginning_of_text"</strong>"Rest_of_text"</div>
```

In this case, if you execute the same command, you'll get this:

```
['   ', '"Rest_of_text"']
```

But in case if there's nothing after the `strong` tag, you'll get this:

```
['   ']
```

The best way to handle all these cases I know is to do the following:

```
>>> full_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//div//text()').extract())
>>> before_strong, after_strong = full_text.split(response.css('strong::text').extract_first())
```

So in the text you've provided, `before_strong` will be equal to `''` and `after_strong` will be equal to `'"Rest_of_text"'`, which seems to be what you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

Only for "Rest_of_text" you can use `response.xpath('//div/strong/following-sibling::text()').get()`